# Cancel button should exit sub

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code that pops up the print window when the user clicks a button. I'm using the following code:

```
Sub printbox()
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
End Sub
```

However, if the user hits "Cancel" an error shows up. Is there a way to fix the code so it exits the sub if they chose cancel?

Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting?  I'm not getting an error when I run what you have posted above.  Is this part of a larger macro?

Comment: With the code you've shown, execution will exit the procedure regardless of what they hit. Can you give us a proper [mcve], and describe the exact specific error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

I cant replicate your issue however you could handle this in the error handler. Just check the error number and if it is not related to the cancellation notify the user.

Change the dummy error number `100` to the error number you're getting.

```
Sub printbox()
    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorTrap:
    If Err.Number <> 100 Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Clicking cancel is interpreted as "vbNullString".

I don't know what your code looks like, but here's an example of something I've used for that:

```
Sub printbox()
Dim UserInput As Variant

UserInput = InputBox("Text")


If UserInput = vbNullString Then     'Exit protocol if cancel is chosen
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Clearly there's more to OP's problem than just what they're showing. Cancelling the dialog doesn't throw any error... and OP is dealing with an error, so, OP's question is incomplete, and this answer doesn't address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple solution:

`If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show = False Then Exit Sub`